# StringIO class does not return expected results in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code that works in python version 2 fails in python 3.

```
AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is the code:

> !pip install
>   warc3-wet

```
import warc
import requests
from contextlib import closing
from io import StringIO

def get_partial_warc_file(url, num_bytes=1024 * 10):
    with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
        buf = StringIO(r.raw.read(num_bytes).decode('utf-8'))  
    return warc.WARCFile(fileobj=buf, compress=True)

urls = {
    'warc': 'https://aws-publicdatasets.s3.amazonaws.com/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-07/segments/1454701145519.33/warc/CC-MAIN-20160205193905-00000-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.gz',
    'wat':  'https://aws-publicdatasets.s3.amazonaws.com/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-07/segments/1454701145519.33/wat/CC-MAIN-20160205193905-00000-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.wat.gz',
    'wet':  'https://aws-publicdatasets.s3.amazonaws.com/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-07/segments/1454701145519.33/wet/CC-MAIN-20160205193905-00000-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.wet.gz'
}

files = {file_type: get_partial_warc_file(url=url) for file_type, url in urls.items()}
```

And here is source:

https://dmorgan.info/posts/common-crawl-python/

---

Update:

This code returns the meta-data of the record, how do I read the news article?

> aws s3 cp --no-sign-request
>   s3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-NEWS/crawl-data/CC-NEWS/2019/08/CC-NEWS-20190824001636-00982.warc.gz

```
import warc

var = 0 

with warc.open("/tmp/CC-NEWS-20190824001636-00982.warc") as f:
    for record in f:
        if var > 1:
            break
        else:
            print (record.date, record.from_response, record.header, record.ip_address, record.offset, record.payload, record.type, record.url, record.write_to)
        var = var + 1
```

Comment: Well yes, you shouldn't expect Python2 code to be compatible with Python 3. In any case, please post the full error message, including the stack trace. Have you tried just subclassing `io.StringIO` and adding a `.name` attribute? Or even just something like `buffer.name = 'foo'`?

Comment: One question per question please: StackOverflow is not set up to be a forum with a continuous conversation with follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that will return the news article source code along with meta-data.

```
# wget https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-07/segments/1454701145519.33/warc/CC-MAIN-20160205193905-00000-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.gz

# gunzip CC-MAIN-20160205193905-00000-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.gz

#!pip install warc3-wet

import warc

var = -10 

with warc.open("CC-MAIN-20160205193905-00000-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc") as f:
    for record in f:
        if var > 1:
            break
        else:
            print (record.payload.read(), record.date, record.from_response, record.header, record.ip_address, record.offset, record.payload, record.type, record.url, record.write_to)
        var = var + 1
```